# R Leaflet map not being created inside for loop in flexdashboard

Tags: r, leaflet, r-markdown, flexdashboard

Leaflet maps can be manually duplicated within the same section, but they do not appear when being called from inside a `for` loop (or a `while` loop). Below is an minimal example. Using `htmltools::tagList` is not an option as I would like to perform actions in between the maps. My question is, then, how can I display  a leaflet map from inside a loop?

````
---
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    source: embed
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r}
library(leaflet)
```

Page 1
============================================
Column 1
--------------------------------------------
### Container

```{r}
leaflet()
```

Column 2
--------------------------------------------
### Container

```{r}
for (i in 1) leaflet()
```
````